# Extjs 4 to 5 migration issue -ext.loader synchronously loading

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Getting this warning while migrating from Ext js 4 to 5

> w ext.loader synchronously loading consider adding ext.require('classname') above ext.onready

Comment: found a similar question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155929/synchronously-loading-consider-adding-ext-require-above-ext-onready) but still  gives no leads to the solution

Answer (score 2):

The warning means the framework encountered a class at runtime that wasn't specified as required by the class that uses it.  The loader goes ahead and loads it but this hurts performance and, if you use Sencha CMD to build the app later, the class may be missed resulting in a runtime error.

Find out where the class is being used and add a "requires" directive.

Comment: This is something that was working in ext 4 without requires directive. I am trying to understand what makes ext 5.1 need to explicitly require the class?